# basic DB polymorphism link

Tags: database, polymorphism

I have a kind of graph, composed of 5 kinds of objects, 1 of them is a link type of object, and the others are the 4 different types of 'nodes' between links.

Each of the 5 is so different that will have a different table.

Each 'node' will have 0..N links 'below', while each link will have exactly 1 'node' below (but of any of 4 kinds). Only things below need to be stored.

So my question is this, is it better in the link table to create 4 columns (node1, node2, node3, node4), and leave 3 of them NULL, the other containing the id of the node, or is it better to have 2 columns (nodetype, nodeId), where 1 tells wich table to search and the other the Id.

For the 0..N relationship I will have to create a new table I supose, but maybe just one to be shared by the 4 types of node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the following for some ideas on how to handle polymorphism in DBs
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html

Comment: A friend of mine is suggesting that I create a single node table with ID, typenode, node1col1, node1col2, node1col3..., node2col1, node2col2... node4colN. This looks bizarre to me, but he knows more than I do.